# Set activity orientation always in reverse Portrait mode in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want to set the orientation of my activity to reversePortrait. To do this, i set the following value in the `activity` of my manifest file:

```
 android:screenOrientation="reversePortait"
```

But this only works you enable "Screen Rotation" from the settings of the device. If "Screen Rotation" is disabled it shows the screen in portrait mode instead of reverse portrait.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

insert
    android:configChanges="orientation"
below 
    android:screenOrientation="reversePortait"

It means the developer takes the whole control of the screen rotation, not the android pattern